# How a custom GWT Editor can know that a new edit begin (before the setValue)

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

If we have an Editor with LeafValue subeditor.
We can implement the interface ValueAwareEditor. with this interface with can implement a flush and a setValue.
But the setValue is called after the driver has set all values in sub editor.
How can we execute code before the driver set values in sub editor. (This may allow to clear the state of the editor).

Is-there an equivalent of the flush method for an edit (or display) cycle in editor ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are re-using Editors trees to edit different objects? Assuming that is the case I don't think there is an event just before setValue. You can always use the EditorVisitor to visit your Editors before you bind a new object?

We throw away the Editor tree each time to try and keep it simpler.

Comment: Yes I reuse the editor for edit different object because it's more efficient than recreate editors.
I will look at the EditorVisitor, thank.

Comment: Even though we don't we reuse we found the need for an event after setValue is finished on the whole tree. A sort of all done now tidy up.

Comment: With the ValueAware, the setValue is called after all update in sub editor. You can use it ?

Comment: True. Might not be needed in that case. However we async fetch meta data (lists of options, tooltips, help etc) so we need an event after that.